# detail in detail sql

Tags: sql, many-to-many, relationship

I have something to ask, hope you guys can give me some advices.

I have `many to many` relationship between `[ORDER] table` and `[PRODUCT] table`.

Now the condition is I need one table again called `[PACKAGE] table` that have `many to many` relationship too with `[PRODUCT] table`.

In this case I want to link the `[PACKAGE] table` to `[ORDER] table`. Because The condition is people can order `item` or order `package` in the `same order form`.

Is it the true way if i just link the `[PACKAGE] table` to `[ORDER] table` ?

Comment: If you have a many to many relationship, then you need a bridge table called orderProducts.  If i understand you correctly, you have package with specific products associated with them.  If this is case, handle this in the business logic of your backend server so that you insert the products from the package into the orderProducts.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options.

The first is to introduce a new table called `OrderPackages` which provides the link to the packages.  However, I don't like this approach, because you cannot easily query for all the items in an order.  The items in the order could be in both `OrderItems` and `OrderPackages`.

SQL is pretty bad at "one-of" types of relationships.  This is what you really want -- an order linked either to an item or to a package, but not both.

My recommendation is to wrap all the items in their own package, and then have an `OrderPackages` table and a `PackageItems` table.  This will make all the querying consistent, and should be pretty easy to implement in any database.

You can automatically create a new package for a new item by using a trigger or wrapping the `insert` code in a stored procedure that does the insert in both tables.